referencing an algorithm mentioned in the preamble of a method claim
a computer-implemented method for awarding winners, the winners determined by an algorithm, comprising:
a) receiving a plurality of exam answers from a first user, the plurality of exam answers associated with a first test; and
b) determining a winner from the first user at least in part on a first condition that the plurality of exam answers pass the first test by the algorithm; and
c) novel inventive step to award the first user;

In this wording of the claim, what it means for an exam to pass a test has been moved to the preamble of the claim.
The purpose is so that it doesn't matter what algorithm is used to determine whether an exam passes a test.
questions:

Is the claim correctly written?
In particular, is the referencing of the algorithm mentioned in the preamble via "the plurality of exam answers pass the first test by the algorithm" correct?
See any grammatical errors?
Will this have the effect of covering all possible algorithms?


Have you considered method steps along the lines of "supplying said scores to a grading logic" and "receiving a grade from said grading logic" to detach from the specific grading algorithm? The specification should explain that the method is orthogonal to the grading algorithm being used. Since the method doesn't "do" the grading per se as a step, it should be not necessary to tie it to a specific grading algorithm.

Of course, one should not overuse this technique, because it risks that whatever is left in the claim is just plain abstract or trivially anticipated.

Thanks for pointing out another cheat code. But does the way that I outline it using the preamble work?

Could you please use capital letters where appropriate in your questions. It improves readability.
